# Change table width in SSRSbased on browser width in report viewer using asp.net

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, report-viewer2010

How to change the report height and width based on browser height and width?

I am using SSRS Sql server 2008 r2. i am working on Report Viewer. report viewer display the RDL report from the server. I have change the size of Report Viewer giving height and width 100%. my report viewer size is now changing based on browser height and width. I give the height of table in SSRS as 100%. SSRS giving it is invalid property. Now i want to change the height and width of table in report based on user browser size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change the reports or tables `Height` and `Width`  according to size of the browser window in `SSRS`. If you are so concerned with the size of the report table you can do it with the use of the `JavaScript` after the report is rendered at the client browser.As for adjusting complete  report you can adjust its size by using the `ReportViewer` properties.

Comment: Can you tell me which property i have to used. I need responsive approach in report viewer using Asp.net

Comment: You are already using it as you mentioned `Report Viewer giving height and width 100%.`. If you want to make it responsive wrap it in the div and make that div responsive.

Comment: can dive make the report to responsive. its not about viewer it is about reporet

Comment: If you want to make the report content responsive then you have to use javascript and do it after report is rendered

Answer (score 1):

apply just this on your css

```
<style>
     table{
    width:100%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: We have property in report Viewer  we have to set  Width="100%" Height="100%"

Comment: Yes, we have this in properties but it doesn't give width to report viewer tables(dynamic created tables) to provide width to dynamic tables we have to apply css.